# Symfony SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused with 1and1 server

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am trying to deploy my symfony api on a 1and1 server. But I can't get pass this error:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: "An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused" ...
```

My Symfony `parameters.yml`:

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3316
    database_name: myDbName
    database_user: MyUserName
    database_password: MyPassword
    database_unix_socket: /tmp/mysql5.sock
```

In the `config.yml` I add the unix_socket:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    unix_socket: "%database_unix_socket%"
    charset:  UTF8
```

Is someone pass thought this error before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed 127.0.0.1 by localhost and now it's working

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified your database parameters?
Try using the default MySQL Port which is **3306**

*parameters.yml*

```
    database_port: 3306
```

OR

Try using the "/tmp/mysql5.sock" instead of "%database_unix_socket%" on your config.yml

*config.yml*

```
    unix_socket: /tmp/mysql5.sock
```